# Any debug facilities to dump control points of a Bézier-curve CGPath

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I just can't imagine why the whole Bézier curve has this shape in my mind without seeing the control points. Is there any facilities for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [a function called `CGPathApply`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathApply) you can use. It takes a pointer to [a function you implement](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGPathApplierFunction), which must take [a structure describing the anchor point](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGPathElement) as its second argument.

Each of those structures includes one or more points. For curve elements, the last one is the next anchor point (where the curve will end up), and the one or two points before that are the control points.